# Spring 5 Reactive Handler Function

Tags: spring, web, reactive

I want to specify a query param in Router Function with Spring 5 web reactive. Here my example:

```
/api/cars?model={model}
```

but when I replace the query param by a value, it is route to the url :

```
/api/cars
```

and not the one with the query param.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the code you have written until now.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, I have found the solution few months ago. I post the code maybe it will helps. Here my  example

```
    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> routerFunction() {
        return route(GET("/cars"), carHandler::handleFindAll)
                .and(route(GET("/cars?model={model}"), carHandler::handleFindAll)); 
// no need tho specify the request param into the route
    }
```

Here my handler

```
   public Mono<ServerResponse> handleFindAll(ServerRequest request) {
        request.queryParam("model"); // will contains the request param ?cars/model=Audi
        return ServerResponse.ok().body(initCars(), Car.class);
    }
```

and how we manage find all and find all with request param